# How to run a python script on android studio

Tags: python, android-studio, flask

I need to know if there is a way to connect my python script to android studio application.
Say i create a python script with a basic "hello world" using flask.
I want a button on my android studio application, which if i click prints that "hello world"

Comment: Well I can guarantee that is is do-able  because I have an app for writing code in python on my android.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Is your app written in Java or Kotlin?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. The app is written in Java @MikePoole

Comment: @MikePoole, Can you share any simple project that uses python script?